# Removing punctuation from a column in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

Can anyone help me in removing punctuation from a column in Power Query?

This is what I'm trying:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Texto em Maiúsculas",{{"descritivo", Text.Select(#"Texto em Maiúsculas"[descritivo], List.Combine({{"A".."Z"},{"a".."z"},{" "}})), type text}})
```

The column is "`descritivo`" and the previous step in Power Query is  `#"Texto em Maiúsculas"`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#"Step" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Texto em Maiúsculas",{{"descritivo", each Text.Combine(List.Select(Text.ToList(_),(x) => List.Contains({"a".."z", "A".."Z", " "},x))), type text}})
```

Comment: Briiliant, a one-liner!